# signature and padding

Tags: java, digital-signature, x.509

I use JcaContentSignerBuilder to sign a self-signed certificate but I don't know what the default padding is. My requirement is that I must NOT use PKCS#1.5 padding. The code I use is below - can someone tell me what padding this is going to generate?

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");

ContentSigner sigGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSAEncryption").setProvider("BC").build(keyPair.getPrivate());

X509Certificate certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(builder.build(sigGen));
```

Best regards, 
Gianpaolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that SHA256WithRSA "implies the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding algorithm [RFC3447]"

See [RFC4051](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4051.txt), 2.3.2.

Sources : [bouncycastle](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/Default-padding-methods-for-asymmetric-RSA-signatures-td4655358.html) , [crypto.stackexchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12973/what-is-the-difference-between-sha256withrsa-and-sha256withrsaencryption-digest)

Comment: Thanks, u r right. Any idea on what algorithms could I use?

Comment: After more research, I found a "SHA256withRSA/PSS", which, as its name says, uses PSS in place of PKCS#1 v1.5. I can't tell you much more about it. Good luck!